# How to extract Urdu text from a webpage using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, decode

I am using bs4 to extract text from a web document. But Its output is very strange. like

```
Ú©Ø¨Ú¾Û ÛÛ Ø¨Ø§Øª Ø³ÙØ¬Ú¾ ÙÛÚº ÙÛ Ø§ÙØªÛ ØªÚ¾ÛÛ Ù¾Ú¾Ø± Ø§ÙÛØ³ØªÛ Ø§ÙÛØ³ØªÛ Ø¬Ø¨ Ú©ÚÚ¾ Ø¹ÙÙ Ø§ÙÙÛ Ø´Ø±ÙØ¹ ÛÙØ¦Û ØªÙ Ø¨Ø§Øª Ú©ÚÚ¾ Ù¾ÙÛ Ù¾ÚÛÛÙÛÚ©Ù Ø§Ø¨ ÛÛ Ø¨Ø§Øª Ø§ÛØ³Û Ø³ÙØ¬Ú¾ ÙÛÚº Ø§ÙØ¦Û Ú©Û Ø³ÙÚØ§ Ø§ÙÙ¾ Ú©ÛÙÙÚ¯ÙÚº Ú©Û Ø¨Ú¾Û Ø´ÛØ¦Ø± Ú©Ø±ÙÚºÛ ÚÙØ¯ Ø±ÙØ² ÙØ¨Ù ÙÛØ±Ø§ 8 Ù
```

I think it is some encoding. I am a new user of bs4. Please guide me how to decode it to show as urdu text.

[Here](http://view-source:http://blog.jang.com.pk/blog_details.asp?id=11055) is a document source whose title I want to extract

Follwoing code I am using to do it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests

url="http://blog.jang.com.pk/blog_details.asp?id=11058"
r  = requests.get(url)

data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
print str(soup.title)
```

Comment: Extracting urdu will work fine… what exactly are you doing?

Comment: I have updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burhan Khalid's answer works, but because the original web page is encoded in utf-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

You should update the requests' response field to match the original page's encoding:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests

url="http://blog.jang.com.pk/blog_details.asp?id=11058"
r  = requests.get(url)
# Update encoding to match source
r.encoding = "utf-8"

data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
print str(soup.title)
```

Now any field you access will have the correct encoding rather than having to set to Urdu on a per field basis.

Comment: If you have control over the document source or the site, you should fix the problem at its source; set the proper Content-Type header, e.g. `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. python-requests will pick up the encoding from HTTP header. Otherwise, you may want to use r.content to get bytes string instead of r.text, and pass the bytes string to beautiful soup. Beautiful Soup will try to guess the encoding based on the embedded meta tag or based on the actual characters on the text.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply try to print the string, you'll get garbage characters out:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
>>> r = requests.get('http://blog.jang.com.pk/blog_details.asp?id=11058')
>>> s = bs4(r.text, 'lxml')
>>> print s.title.text
Ú©ÚÚ¾ ØªÙØ¬Û Ø§Ø³ Ø·Ø±Ù Ø¨Ú¾Û!
```

You need to *encode* it properly, since the result is a unicode bytestring.

```
>>> print s.title.text.encode('iso-8859-1')
کچھ توجہ اس طرف بھی!
```

If it displays the glyphs correctly, but in the wrong order (ie, they are not right-to-left), then this is a problem with your operating system/terminal/shell/program you are using to run the application.

The above is from gnome-terminal, which doesn't support Arabic RTL properly.

If I run the same code in mlterm:

[image]

*The white box is there because I am using an Arabic font, which doesn't have all the characters in the Urdu language*.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening is that there some badly formed Unicode in the website response:

```
----> 1 r.content.decode()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 1106: invalid continuation byte
```

Hence the text is being decoded using the `ANSI` codec which is obviously wrong. You can work around this issue by calling decode with the option `errors='ignore'` (we are using the `content` rather than `text` because this is the raw binary response from the website:

```
data = r.content.decode(errors='ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
print (str(soup.title))
<title>کچھ توجہ اس طرف بھی!</title>
```